# No way to update python3.10 on my linux mint mate 20.3 Una

Tags: linux-mint, python-3.10

Last night the update manager indicates there are 2 update ready. I want to apply them but at the end  only one updates the 2nd one (python 3.10) does not. It was late so went to bed. This morning that update is still there but now there is some more stuff.

> Skipping acquire of configured file 'main/binary-i386/Packages' as repository 'http://apt.postgresql.org/pub/repos/apt focal-pgdg InRelease' doesn't support architecture 'i386'

It was not exactly the same as mine related to codelite. I looked in repositories and ppa´s  and found an entry for codelite and disabled it. That message was gone. But the update still did not work. This time a problem with the mirror I was using. Changed mirror and all the rest runs fine. Still updating python 3.10 no way. Other updates do pass, even python 3.8 and 3.9. Clearly the problem lies with python 3.10 and seem dependency related but I am stumped.

The deadsnakes repository is there. I removed and reinstalled it. Still same problem.

Here is a screen shoot of my terminal (same messages appear when I use synaptic):
[image]

It all turn around two dependencies that python 3.10 needs but are no longer there. But the recommended commands do nothing but return the same result.

> The following packages have unmet dependencies.
> python3.10 : Depends: libpython3.10-stdlib (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed
> python3.10-minimal : Depends: libpython3.10-minimal (= 3.10.4-1+focal2) but 3.10.4-1+focal1 is installed

So what is going wrong? what apart from focal1 and focal2 is different? And are they fundamentally different? Most importantly how do I solve this problem without going in circles.

Oh and before I forget. My python console in gedit stopped working at the same time as these problems started and I can't make out what the problem there is either. Suspect though they are related. e

Thank you in advance.

Comment: [This](https://askubuntu.com/a/1402415) is what solved the exact same issue for me (Lubuntu 20.04.4 LTS).

Comment: [Please don't add "solved" to your title or question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/116105/248627). Instead, [mark an answer correct by clicking on the ✔](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/248627). You can also [add your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer) and accept it if none of the ones you received solved your problem.

Comment: thank you Chris for pointing that out. Thing is the link in the comment by sgrontflix was sufficient to solve the problem but I could not click that one. But will keep that in mind. Was a long time since I was on Stackflow and was out of date with procedures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same error. I followed the instructions in the first and second answer and I got this:

[/var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.debE: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hIoSG.png)

After move this :
[sudo mv /var/cache/apt/archives/libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb /tmp](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TZM4g.png)

It works !

Answer (score 12):

Here is how I solved the same issue in Ubuntu 20.04

Locate package libpython3.10-stdlib

```
$ apt-cache policy libpython3.10-stdlib
libpython3.10-stdlib:
  Installed: 3.10.4-1+focal1
  Candidate: 3.10.4-1+focal2
  Version table:
     3.10.4-1+focal2 500
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/deadsnakes/ppa/ubuntu focal/main amd64 Packages
 *** 3.10.4-1+focal1 100
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status

$ ls -l /var/lib/dpkg/info | grep -i libpython3.10-stdlib
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   14489 Apr 10 00:26 libpython3.10- stdlib:amd64.list
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root   23536 Mär 24 17:12 libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64.md5sums
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root    1161 Mär 24 17:12 libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64.prerm
```

Remove manually the package

```
$ sudo mv /var/lib/dpkg/info/libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64.* /tmp
```

Repeat the same steps for libpython3.10-minimal. Then fix the broken packages

```
$ sudo apt --fix-broken install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
The following packages will be upgraded:
  libpython3.10-minimal libpython3.10-stdlib
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 8 not upgraded.
5 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/2.566 kB of archives.
After this operation, 68,6 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64'    missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
dpkg: warning: files list file for package 'libpython3.10-minimal:amd64' missing; assuming package has no files currently installed
(Reading database ... 191581 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-stdlib_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over  (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
Preparing to unpack .../libpython3.10-minimal_3.10.4-1+focal2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) over (3.10.4-1+focal1) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-minimal:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up python3.10-minimal (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-stdlib:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up libpython3.10:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up python3.10 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up libpython3.10-dev:amd64 (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
Setting up python3.10-dev (3.10.4-1+focal2) ...
```

Comment: I had to do at the end "sudo apt-get -f install", thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Same thing happened to me. When apt fails I go for https://pkgs.org/, search the package, download and install manually. It usually works.